# Unable to load tensorflow model in Java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have created a servable LSTM model in Python but when I try to use the model in Java I get an error.

Here is my Java code to load the model:

```
org.tensorflow.Session session = SavedModelBundle.load(myModelDirectory, "serve").session();
```

Here is the error I encounter:

```
 Loading SavedModel from ...: 
[libprotobuf ERROR external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:287] Error parsing text-format tensorflow.SavedModel: 80:13: Unknown enumeration value of "DT_VARIANT" for field "type".
```

I have checked the saved_model.pbtxt for servable model and find quite a few references to 'type: DT_VARIANT'

My python code uses tensorflow tf-nightly 1.5x build. I have also tried this with tf1.4 library. In Java, I am using libtensorflow-1.5.0-rc0.jar. I have also tried unsuccessfully loading the model alongwith libtensorflow-1.4.0.jar and libtensorflow-1.3.0.jar jar files.

When I look at the history of tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/types.proto in github, I notice that DT_VARIANT and uint32/uint64 were added in July 2017 and Oct 2017 respectively so maybe thats why the jar files are not able to recognize them. I have checked in tensorflow/tensorflow/java/src/ and havent noticed any reference to these types. So maybe that is the problem.

Sorry if Im missing something obvious, I have tried looking around for an answer. Does anyone have any suggestions I can try to get around this problem?

Comment: You already figure out everything by yourself :) Looks like java package is too old and not compatible with tensorflow 1.4+ (especially nightly/beta version)

Comment: Thanks @Aiven. Do you know if there is a newer jar that I can use? The latest I can find is libtensorflow-1.5.0-rc0.jar. 
Or is there any other way I can load my model in Java? I would like to get it to work in Java :)

Comment: not sure about new java package, but you can also try to retrain model with even older tf version

Comment: `DT_VARIANT` did exist in 1.4 (see [source in release branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/framework/types.proto)).  Could it be possible that your classpath is somehow setup in a way that you're using an even older version of the Java packages? I'd suggest that you verify the TensorFlow version being used in your Java program. `System.out.println(TensorFlow.version())` should help you figure that out (see [`TensorFlow.version`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/TensorFlow.html#version()))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendation! When I tried to print the tensorflow version, Java printed out 1.3.0. Upon looking further I found out that eventhough I had added libtensorflow-1.5.0-rc0.jar to my project in eclipse, I hadnt added the appropriate tensorflow_jni.dll so Java was using tensorflow 1.3. Once I added the the correct tensorflow_jni.dll, my model was loaded successfully. Thanks again!

Comment: If you use Maven/Gradle or something, I'd suggest having your project depend on the [`org.tensorflow:tensorflow`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.tensorflow%22%20AND%20a%3A%22tensorflow%22) artifact. It's a single artifact so you don't have to worry about consistency between the Java and native code.